# How can i find out the difference between two thrift structs?

Tags: c++, struct, thrift

I have two thrift struct of same type.

```
struct NestedObject {
  1: string name
  2: i64 version
}
struct Object {
  1: string name
  2: i64 version
  3: NestedObject object; 
  4: XYZ ..;
  5: CBDE ..;
  // and tons of fields
}
```

I have Object A and Object B and i want to find which fields differ between two objects A and B?
I wouldn't want to write a simple comparison function to check A.name == B.name && A.object.name == B.object.name as this list can grow indefinitely.

Comment: You will have to write a function (possibly `Object operator-(const Object& a, const Object& b)` - but just a plain function would also work).

Comment: Ah, I should have made the question more clearer.
The number of fields will keep on increasing and i don't want to change the ::diff function all the time. There are around 100 fields today in this struct.

Comment: I don't think there is a simple way to do this, aside from perhaps some auto-generated code, or using some sort of offset-table perhaps. If you hae a language that has reflection (ability to "understand" objects within the code), you could perhaps use that. But C++ won't.

Comment: **How is that related to Thrift?** I mean, you have that very problem with any kind of `structs`, regardless whether they are Thrift-generated or not. If you are looking for some special magic: Nope, there is none.